# NestJS class-validator generic enum

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, nestjs, class-validator

I am trying to create a generic DTO class for sorting via query params, the generic accepts the schema class and the properties that are permitted to be sorted on. But as you know "K" in this case is union type which can not be iterated so creating the enum that will be passed to the "@IsEnum" is not possible at the moment. I am trying for hours but i can't  find the solution.

```
enum SortDirection {
  ASC = 'asc',
  DESC = 'desc',
}

export class SortQueryDto<T, K extends keyof T> {
  @IsEnum(K) // This doesn't work
  @IsNotEmpty()
  field: K;

  @IsEnum(SortDirection)
  @IsNotEmpty()
  direction: SortDirection;
}


export class TasksFilterQueryDto {
  @ValidateNested()
  @IsArray()
  @IsOptional()
  @Type(() => SortQueryDto)
  sorts?: SortQueryDto<
    Task,
    | 'createdAt'
    | 'updatedAt'
    | 'title'
    | 'approvedAt'
    | 'doneAt'
    | 'dueDate'
    | 'important'
  >[];
}
```